# EF Core relationship misunderstanding

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm pretty new with Entity Framework and I'm getting pretty confused on how to define things code first.

I'd just to define in code this simple relationship: I have an entity Meal that represents what I'm gonna eat today.

```
public class Meal
{
    public int MealId { get; set; }
    public DayOfWeek DayOfWeek { get; set; }
    public Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
    public int RecipeId { get; set; }
    public WeeklySchedule WeeklySchedule { get; set; }
}
```

The class recipe that you see represent the recipe I'm gonna use to cook that meal.
So the relationship is one to many. Many meals can use the same recipe, but any meal has only one recipe

The class recipe:

```
public class Recipe
{
    public int RecipeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<RecipeItem> RecipeItems { get; set; }
}
```

And the weekly schedule:

```
public class WeeklySchedule
{
    public int WeeklyScheduleId { get; set; }
    public int WeekNumber { get; set; }
    public List<Meal> Meals { get; set; }

    public WeeklySchedule() { }

    public WeeklySchedule(int weeknumber)
    {
        WeekNumber = weeknumber;
        Meals = new List<Meal>();
    }
}
```

When I create the model I define:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Recipe>().HasMany(c => c.RecipeItems).WithOne(c => c.Recipe).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade); 
modelBuilder.Entity<RecipeItem>().HasMany(c => c.RecipeItemComponents).WithOne(c => c.RecipeItem).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade); 
modelBuilder.Entity<WeeklySchedule>().HasMany(c => c.Meals).WithOne(c => c.WeeklySchedule).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade); 
modelBuilder.Entity<Meal>().HasOne(c => c.Recipe);
```

I use this code to store it:

```
_context.WeeklySchedules.Add(weeklySchedule);
 await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

My problem is that when I try to save a new meal, I get the error:

> SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in
>   table 'Recipes' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Even though in my case I don't want to create a Recipe, but I'm creating just a meal pointing to an existing Recipe.

I think that I'm creating the model in the wrong way.

Could you help me understand what's what?

Comment: Don't use shadow properties, they are nothing but confusing. Add `public int RecipeId { get; set; }` to the Meal entity

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I just added the RecipeId, migrated, updated the db but nothing changed

Comment: Can you share the code? This happens if you try to use an unattached entity

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto sure. What part of the code is significant here?

Comment: As much code as you consider relevant to adding the new Meal, specially from where the Recipe object comes from. (Note: the fastest answer is: use `Meal.RecipeId` instead of `Meal.Recipe`)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I updated the question with more code

Comment: I didn't mean that, I meant where you use `context.Meals.Add(...`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I added the weeksly schedule too, probably it completes the picture better